# How to round outputFields of type=Decimal in a VF email template?

Tags: email-template

I am working with visualforce template i am getting all decimal values in my mail but i want to round it in Max upto 2 decimals

```
      SubTotal  $90.0000
 Shipping & handling     $2.000
Grand Total(Excl.Tax)   $92.000
         Tax    $8.170
 Grand Total(Incl.Tax)  $100.1700
```

My Template Code

```
       <messaging:emailTemplate recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Quote__c" subject="Your requested quote #{!relatedTo.Name}" >
      <messaging:htmlEmailBody>
                <apex:outputField value="{!relatedTo.Total_Price__c}"/>
              <apex:outputField value="{!relatedTo.Total_Shipping__c}"/>   
            <apex:outputField value="{!relatedTo.Gtotal__c}"/>
     </messaging:htmlEmailBody>

     </messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for VF functions ( http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm ) and try to answer your own question.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke   <apex:outputField value="{!ROUND(relatedTo.Total_Price__c,2)}"/ i tried like this but it showing Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'

Comment: Then, in one of the lines you may have forgotten to put a ")" ?

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke value for <apex:outputField value="{ROUND(!relatedTo.Total_Price__c,3)}"/>      <apex:outputField> is not a dynamic binding! in this case this errpr

Comment: Sathya - you are misunderstanding how expressions work in VF - the correct syntax is as Samuel De Rycke stated - `<apex:outputField value="{!ROUND(relatedTo.Total_Price__c,3)}"/>`  The `{!` appears at the beginning of the expression and you don't embed `{!` again in the expression

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

1. You can create formula fields to calculate and round the decimal values you need in the template. This has the benefit of letting you tweak the formula, and see the result until you have it just like you want it. It also has the added benefit of getting your complex formulas out of the view layer (the template) and into the model layer(object).
2. Secondly, you can utilize inline functions to accomplish this within your template. In your case you'd want a merge expression something like this:

   {!ROUND(relatedTo.Total_Price__c,3)}

I prefer using #1, as it keeps the templates stupid simple and maintains a separation of concerns. But it's a trade off in dev speed.

Comment: <apex:outputField value="{!ROUND(relatedTo.Total_Price__c,3)}"/> it showing Syntax missing in )' <apex:outputField value="{!relatedTo.Total_Price__c}"/> it is working fine.